# Error in installing gsconfig Python library for manipulating a GeoServer instance via the GeoServer RESTConfig API

Tags: python, geoserver

I like to install gsconfig Python libraries I got error like this

```
Collecting gsconfig
 Downloading gsconfig-0.6.13.tar.gz
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module
 Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
 Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 20, in <module

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\new\
AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-5luj5ufr\gsconfig
```

Comment: Can you give us more details about the method you used for installation??

Comment: I am using python 3.x but gsconfig is written in python 2.x. That's why I faced this problem.

Comment: Ok. I guess you should write it as an answer and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Actually gsconfig is now supporting python 3.x:

Just follow the steps:

1. `git clone https://github.com/boundlessgeo/gsconfig.git`
2. `cd gsconfig`
3. `python setup.py install`

You are all set.